# How do I get the overall maximum value in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to have the program take the user's input then put it into a 2d array then I want it to find the overall maximum number from all the numbers and print it. I dont know much about 2d arrays yet so I dont where the logic error is.

Heres my code :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoTwo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numbers[][] = new int[3][3], max[][] = new int[3][3], n, temp;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
                numbers[i][j] = obj.nextInt();
            }
        }
        max[0][0] = numbers[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (numbers[i][j] > max[0][0]) {
                    max[0][0] = numbers[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < max.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < max.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(max[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While possible, it is not suggested to write the array-backets after the variable-name, but after the thype. --- We normally do not write multipel declarations in one line. --- Why do you use `int[][] max`, if you need only a single max value?

Comment: Why use 2d array just to find maximum input value?

Comment: @Turing85 Im new to 2d arrays and there concept isn't clear about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program more or less works as you want but definitely can be improved. The result is currently just displayed with 8 zeros appended. This happens because you are looping over `max` to print and only the first entry is actually set.

*Suggestions on how to improve:*

- Use a single integer (`int max = 0;`) for storing the resulting maximum. An array is not needed for this.
- Do not write multiple declarations on the same line since this is discouraged in for Java and a potential source of bugs (hard to read).
- Give the instance of the *Scanner* a meaningful name (e.g. `scanner`) instead of `obj`.
- Use `numbers.length` and `numbers[0].length` instead of a hardcoded number to make avoid problems when changing the range later on.
- Use Java-style array declarations (`int[] name`) instead of C-style array declarations (`int name[]`).

*Your whole class could look like this:*

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] numbers = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
                numbers[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
                if (numbers[i][j] > max) {
                    max = numbers[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

If the maximum does not need to be calculated in a separate step, you could put the if-statement directly in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoTwo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numbers[][] = new int[3][3], max[][] = new int[3][3], n, temp;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
                numbers[i][j] = obj.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int maxVal = -Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (numbers[i][j] > maxVal) {
                    maxVal = numbers[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code by using *streams*:

```java
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 4}, {32, 23}};

int max = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                .max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

System.out.println(max); // 32
```